# Generating Random number in assembly

Tags: assembly, random, tasm

Using tasm here. I am making a snake game, I have successfully programmed the moving part, Now I wish to generate the "food" of the snake randomly. in c or java, we have a random function but not in assembly. Is there any way to include c function for generating random values? 
CAN ANYONE GUIDE ME HOW?

Comment: Sure, both, you can use the same algorithm as any other language and/or you simply call a C function.

Comment: You could do that, but that kind of defeats the point of writing the game in ASM, doesn't it? I would suggest reading up on how linear congruential random number generators work, those are easy to implement in ASM as well.

Comment: @us2012 Sure it would, reading upon that now, but any guide on how to include a c function in asm?

Comment: The short version is "follow the relevant calling conventions and make sure you link it properly". Unfortunately, I don't know much about TASM and the organisation of the C runtime library in Windows, so I can't help you with details for your configuration.

Comment: If you rename your game to `nsake`, you can use Intel's `RDRAND` instruction to get a "random" number.

Comment: @kerrekSB why 'nsnake' if I may ask? secondly can 'RDRAND' be used on emu8086?

Comment: I don't know emu8086, you have to check which instructions it supports. RDRAND is new in Intel Ivy Bridge. It produces what looks like a random number, but is assumed to be designed by the NSA to be predictable once you know how it works, effectively creating a master key to cryptographic protocols that rely solely on this instruction as a source of randomness.

Comment: @kerreksb why renaming it to 'nsnake' ?

Comment: @worriednacho I guess it's a joke about concerns over the NSA possibly inserting backdoors in RDRAND

Comment: One of Marsaglia's Xorshift generators would probably be the best for this use: fast and easy to implement in assembly, requires small state-space, good statistical properties. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift

Comment: nevermind fellows..generated my own random number logic using some algorithms from previous random number generators and mixing it up.. It worked wonders :D.. Anyway, thank you everyone :)